# PHP how to fetch image from image folder using id

Tags: php, mysql

i have write a code for browsing a file images and upload it into specified folder using php.now i want a mysql database where i make a two field name id and name where i can store my browse file name into the database . Then i want to fetch the image from the folder using id.

please write a code for the fetch a image from id into specific folder.

Comment: Nobody is going to write code for you.

Comment: I liked the `please` on `please write a code`

Comment: For starters, i doubt anybody will wrote you the code. But ... I am willing to point you in the right direction. It is a select statement in mysql, where you pick up the URL where it is stored. Or add a 3rd field to your database. add the articleid, or whatever id you have where the image should be loading into.

Answer (score 0):

As a solution to the problem you need to specify fixed path for image folder and define a field in database for storing file name for image.

Then you can fetch image using path defined for image folder along with file name retrieved for image from database.

e.g.

```
  <img src="<?php echo $Path.'/'.$record['image_filename'];?>">
```